# Encrypting and Decrypting data through transport through Java to Node.js

Tags: java, node.js, encryption, cryptography

I'm trying to send data from Java (Android) to an Node.js application, except the encryption isn't working and Node.js is not decrypting properly, and I don't really have a clue what I'm doing.

Java:

```
                    // Encrypt
                    byte[] input = jo.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

                    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
                    byte[] thedigest = md.digest(ENCRYPTION_KEY.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                    SecretKeySpec skc = new SecretKeySpec(thedigest, "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
                    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
                    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skc);

                    byte[] cipherText = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(input.length)];
                    int ctLength = cipher.update(input, 0, input.length, cipherText, 0);
                    ctLength += cipher.doFinal(cipherText, ctLength);
                    String query = Base64.encodeToString(cipherText, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

`query` is then sent to our server and `jo` is an `JSONObject`

And over in Node, I'm doing:

```
        var decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes-128-ecb', encryption_key);
        console.log("System: " + new Buffer(fullBuffer, "base64").toString("binary") );

        chunks = []
        chunks.push( decipher.update( new Buffer(fullBuffer, "base64").toString("binary") , 'hex', 'utf-8') );
        chunks.push( decipher.final('utf-8') );
        var txt = chunks.join("");

        console.log("System: " + txt);
        js = JSON.parse(txt);
        console.log("System: " + js);
```

And `fullBuffer` is the received POST data which transfers over correctly

Comment: so, what's the question?

Comment: How do I encrypt data properly in Java, and then decrypt it in Node.js using AES

Comment: I see an accepted answer, Joe, but what did actually solve your issue?

Comment: I'm not really too sure... I just fiddled with it and it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encryption and authentication is brutal to debug because any mistake you make results in randomizing the whole output. Suggestions:

1. Switch to a non-encrypted transform like Base64 or gzip so that you can see what your output looks like.
2. Try to figure out which half is broken. Capture your server output and decode it with openssl or python. Generate some good input with one of those and stuff it into your client.
3. CBC is much more secure than ECB.
4. If none of that helps, step into the low level cipher and decipher and make sure the keys and ciphertexts match exactly in content and length, and squint at the algorithm selection long and hard.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't use CBC without it breaking. Code: https://gist.github.com/3111592